# Sessions in php do not load profiles, php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli, profile

I need to be able to orientate with a php code that communicates with data from a mysql database, this file is called "validate.php". Its main functions are to verify that there are no empty fields at the time of login, and assign a profile if a user has value 1 and another profile when the value is 0 in the records of the table "users"

The idea is that "validate.php" check the user and direct it to a page according to their profile, but I can not do that.

My code is:

```
<?php
require('access_db.php'); 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['send'])) { // We verify that the form data has been sent
    //We verify that the user_name and the user_pass fields are not empty
    if(empty($_POST['user_name']) || empty($_POST['user_pass'])) {
    echo"
    <script>
      alert('Please enter your username and password correctly ');
      location.replace('login.php');
    </script>
  ";
   }else {
        //"Clean" the form fields of possible malicious code
        $user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,trim($_POST['user_name']));
        $user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,trim($_POST['user_pass']));
        // We verify that the data entered in the form match those of the DB
        $query=mysqli_query($link,"select user_id,user_name,user_admin FROM users WHERE user_name='".$user_name."' and user_pass ='".$user_pass."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row["user_name"];
$_SESSION['user_admin'] = $row["user_admin"];
 if($_SESSION['user_admin']==1){
  echo "dashboard.php";
   }else{
    echo "dashboard2.php";
 }

    {
        }

}else{
    header("Location: login.php");
}?>
```

My main problem is here:

```
if($_SESSION['user_admin']==1){
  echo "dashboard.php";
   }else{
    echo "dashboard2.php";
 }
```

When I login with my admin user in my page "login.php" you should check the information and go to a page according to your profile, only appears in the browser "http://localhost/proyect/validate.php" and the text "dashboard" on the page, But, if I write in the browser "http://localhost/proyect/dashboard.php" load the page with all the information.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
Someone can help me, I'll be very grateful, I've been on this for days.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you printing on screen when you want to redirect them.

Comment: Do you store the passwords in clear text in the database? **Don't store passwords in clear text!** Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection - use prepared statements rather than directly embedding variables in the sql

Comment: @programmingArrow, hello, my idea was not to print information, as you say, i want to redirect to my pages by profile, thanks to Magnus Eriksson

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Thank you very much for your advice !!! 
I am learning to program, I make mistakes but thanks to the community, I will learn more.

Comment: @RamRaider,  I'm newbie to do this, thanks a lot, I will learn about you mention. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print, try this instead:

```
if($_SESSION['user_admin']==1){
       header('location:dashboard.php');
       exit;
}else{
       header('location:dashboard2.php');
       exit;
}
```

Thanks for the suggestion Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Thanks for your help, modify and finally enter to my profiles.

Answer (score 1):

you need to redirect not echo out the contents of the php file
and also do check for { as there are extra ones

```
if($_SESSION['user_admin']==1){
       header("Location: dashboard.php");
       }else{
        header("Location: dashboard2.php");
     }
```

Comment: Don't forget to have `exit;` after the headers to make sure that the headers gets sent straight away and nothing after gets parsed.